# WinAPI / WPF: Set system cursor only for application

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, winapi, cursor

I have an application whose UI is custom rendered with a theme. I also want to add new non-default-cursors (like the resize cursors when the user intends to resize the window) to match that theme.

With the WinAPI function `SetCursor` I am only able to change the default pointer for the application, but this is not enough, so I looked up `SetSystemCursor` which works just fine. Problem is: The latter version changes the cursors system-wide permanently, but I only want them to be changed for my application only.

I thought about copying the previous cursors before I do the `SetSystemCursor` and re-set them at application exit, but even when I implement a terminate handler it may not be called if the process e.g. just crashes. Also the cursors would still be changed system-wide as long as the application is running.

Specifically for the resize-cursors, I could just drop the window style, make a borderless window, and render/implement the resizing grips and logic myself (then I could just hook the mouse-over events), but that is really just my last resort - I'd rather like to know if it is possible achieve my goal before I do this cumbersome task...

For anyone who is interested: The UI is rendered with WPF, but WPF doesn't provide this functionality either (again, they have it, but just for the default pointer). It's no concern for me to use the WinAPI or other "low-level" calls if I have to, but at the moment it seems there are none that are fitting my needs :(

So if anybody knows how to change the other system cursors (not the default pointer) in WPF or WinAPI just for my application without having to implement custom cursor-logic to my window just for that, you would make my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to implement this in WPF, but if you want to set the cursor to something other than default, then your window procedure should handle the WM_SETCURSOR message.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wow, that might actually work! I just hooked the WndProc of my WPF window and intercepted all WM_SETCURSOR messages (so this works). If I handle the message, the cursor is not set by WPF/Windows, so I could be able to calculate where the mouse currently is within the client/non-client area and set my cursor accordingly. I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: The LOWORD of the lParam argument tells you which area of the non-client area the cursor is over.

Comment: Works perfectly! By intercepting the WM_SETCURSOR message and evaluating the hit-test code of the lo-word (HT*) I was able to change the cursors as I needed! Downside is that triggers and setters that are targeting the `Cursor` property of a `FrameworkElement` doesn't have any effect anymore when the HTCLIENT hit-test is handled; but that is expected behavior. My whole cursor handling is now customized. And it's good to know that this works with WPF. Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you tried calling the default handler / method for the conditions that you do not want to change the cursor?  That may help on your downside--or not...

Comment: Sorry, I might have not been clear enough: If I handle the message for a HTCLIENT hit-test, then the WPF bindings do not work. The trick is, to just NOT handle the HTCLIENT ;) By doing so I can still use the regular `Cursor` property and my custom cursor handling just for the rest. When leaving HTCLIENT unhandled, WPF/Windows will still work with its default behavior. I added this to my comment because I wanted to mention this for others in case someone reads this answer and comments :)